# DateTime.Now causes IO blocking?

Tags: c#

On a conference someone told me that `DateTime.Now` causes IO blocking, something that I have never stopped to consider.  If it does, why?

Comment: May I ask why you didn't ask the person who told it to you?

Comment: Strange why this question gets so many upvotes with so few background informations. My next question: _"I've heard that too many stackoverflow exceptions can cause the computer to blow, if it does, why??"_

Comment: It is a provocative question.  What was the theme of the conference?  .Net in general?  Windows phone?  XNA?

Comment: This is the first time I've heard anything about it. MSDN does say you for example shouldn't use DateTime.Now for performance testing, but it only explains that by saying it doesn't have a good resolution.

Comment: I'm not sure it's an issue of *I/O* blocking necessarily so much as it's that a system call is likely being made, and thus, just as when you make a call to an I/O function, you give the system a chance to take control from your process and give it to another.

Comment: Sorry if the question lacked info, but that's really all the info i got. I didn't got the chance to ask more details, we were at the middle of a convention, i searched for more info on the matter but couldn't find anything. Sorry about the poor English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nobody so far has answered where the current time is really coming from. I'm not up to date with the latest PC architecture. But a few years ago, the [real-time clock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_clock) was part of a chip outside of the CPU (south bridge). So to get the time, you had to do some I/O operations with that chip. (It's not disk access but still an I/O operation.)

And since the current process has to wait for the answer from the clock, it's blocking I/O.

So that person on the conference was right.

Answer (score 5):

Well, considering that

using [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) on `mscorelib` we can find out, that `DateTime.Now`, appears in this way:

```
public static DateTime Now
{
    get
    {
        DateTime utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
        bool isAmbiguousDst = false;
        long ticks = TimeZoneInfo.GetDateTimeNowUtcOffsetFromUtc(utcNow, out isAmbiguousDst).Ticks;
        long num = utcNow.Ticks + ticks;
        if (num > 3155378975999999999L)
        {
            return new DateTime(3155378975999999999L, DateTimeKind.Local);
        }
        if (num < 0L)
        {
            return new DateTime(0L, DateTimeKind.Local);
        }
        return new DateTime(num, DateTimeKind.Local, isAmbiguousDst);
    }
}
```

The function `GetDateTimeNowUtcOffsetFromUtc` appears like:

```
internal static TimeSpan GetDateTimeNowUtcOffsetFromUtc(DateTime time, out bool isAmbiguousLocalDst)
{
    isAmbiguousLocalDst = false;
    TimeZoneInfo.OffsetAndRule oneYearLocalFromUtc = TimeZoneInfo.GetOneYearLocalFromUtc(time.Year);
    TimeSpan timeSpan = oneYearLocalFromUtc.offset;
    if (oneYearLocalFromUtc.rule != null)
    {
        bool isDaylightSavingsFromUtc = TimeZoneInfo.GetIsDaylightSavingsFromUtc(time, time.Year, oneYearLocalFromUtc.offset, oneYearLocalFromUtc.rule, out isAmbiguousLocalDst);
        timeSpan += (isDaylightSavingsFromUtc ? oneYearLocalFromUtc.rule.DaylightDelta : TimeSpan.Zero);
    }
    return timeSpan;
}
```

`GetOneYearLocalFromUtc` instead appears like:

```
private static TimeZoneInfo.OffsetAndRule GetOneYearLocalFromUtc(int year)
{
    if (TimeZoneInfo.s_oneYearLocalFromUtc == null || TimeZoneInfo.s_oneYearLocalFromUtc.year != year)
    {
        TimeZoneInfo currentOneYearLocal = TimeZoneInfo.GetCurrentOneYearLocal();
        TimeZoneInfo.AdjustmentRule rule = (currentOneYearLocal.m_adjustmentRules == null) ? null : currentOneYearLocal.m_adjustmentRules[0];
        TimeZoneInfo.s_oneYearLocalFromUtc = new TimeZoneInfo.OffsetAndRule(year, currentOneYearLocal.BaseUtcOffset, rule);
    }
    return TimeZoneInfo.s_oneYearLocalFromUtc;
}
```

finally `GetCurrentOneYearLocal` appears like:

```
private static TimeZoneInfo GetCurrentOneYearLocal()
{
    Win32Native.TimeZoneInformation timeZoneInformation = default(Win32Native.TimeZoneInformation);
    long num = (long)UnsafeNativeMethods.GetTimeZoneInformation(out timeZoneInformation);
    TimeZoneInfo result;
    if (num == -1L)
    {
        result = TimeZoneInfo.CreateCustomTimeZone("Local", TimeSpan.Zero, "Local", "Local");
    }
    else
    {
        result = TimeZoneInfo.GetLocalTimeZoneFromWin32Data(timeZoneInformation, false);
    }
    return result;
}
```

The interesting function is `GetTimeZoneInformation`, present in `kernel32.dll` which described in documentation like:

> Retrieves the current time zone settings. These settings control the
>   translations between Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) and local time.

To access that time information Windows actually uses `IO` access. Not sure if this *can* be defined like a "blocking", but it's definitely acessing system information saved on the disk, at least part of it.

Comment: Anyway, suprising what all happens on a heavily used property like `DateTime.Now`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: this is actually those kind of questions that persons like me can express only suppositions. Cause only the person that *actually* implemented this in Windows OS (that *can* vary, I immagine, between different versions) can give an **exact** answer.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: So I **suppose** that its read from disk, considering also other documentation about, for example, [DYNAMIC_TIME_ZONE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724253(v=vs.85).aspx) where information stored in registry, so has to be also read from it. Which doesn't mean, con not say no, that OS can cash it on startup and read it from memory (doubt actually, most probabbly from some memory mapped file).

Comment: @Tigran: The time zone information will sooner or later be cached. But the current time is retrieved from the south bridge chip (or it's equivalent) and that requires blocking I/O. So the really interesting part is not in the .NET code, but in `GetTimeZoneInformation`.

Comment: @Codo: that's actually what my answer is all about :)

Comment: great answer, so much better than mine and it has same number of upvotes (atleast before mine), SO sometimes looks like speed answer contest :(

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the source with some reflector like tool DateTime.Now calls Win API [GetSystemTimeAsFileTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724397%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and after that it creates new DateTime object using [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2xf7zzk.aspx) that have one int64 parameter with ticks since January 1, 0001 at 00:00:00.000. Don't see anything here that could cause I/O blocking, and there is no mention of that in GetSystemTimeAsFileTime documentation.

Comment: I guess you missed where the current time is really coming from: the south-bridge chip. To access it, I/O is needed and it's blocking.