# DateTime precision?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

*(ignoring the optimized compiler flag )*

can it be that this code will enter the block on some systems ?

```
if (Datetime.Now!=Datetime.Now)
{
 ...
}
```

I mean , how does it evaluate the values here ? (is it by order) ?

Is there any situations where the condition *might* be true ?

again , *ignore* the optimized flag.

Comment: On a really slow system I guess. You just need a 1 tick stall between the calls to make them different.

Comment: I loved this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2143784/570150

Comment: @leppie where "tick" means the system timer running, and not the `Tick` unit that represents 100ns.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: No, I meant the latter. Or at least some form of it rounded, eg `49.9ns vs 50ns`

Comment: @leppie Write a test program, and you'll see that it'll only change every 1-16ms on a typical windows system.

Comment: @leppie a typical value is `23:59:59.9999999` and is much smaller than 1-16 ms... ( the 9999999 ).... no?

Comment: @RoyiNamir It displays those digits yes, but you'll see that they don't change individually. They'll stay the same until the millisecond part changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DateTime.Now` calls internally :

```
public static DateTime Now
{
    get
    {
        return DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime();
    }
}
```

which calls internally:

```
public static DateTime UtcNow
{
    get
    {
        long systemTimeAsFileTime = DateTime.GetSystemTimeAsFileTime();
        return new DateTime((ulong)(systemTimeAsFileTime + 504911232000000000L | 4611686018427387904L));
    }
}
```

where [GetSystemTimeAsFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685762/windows-7-timing-functions-how-to-use-getsystemtimeadjustment-correctly) is WindowsAPI function that return *system* clock information. The accurasy depends on system, so.

If you have a delay, for some reason between different gets (`DateTime.Now` ) it **may** produce different enough result that equality comparer fails. But I, personally, never met this kind of condition in my experience.

Comment: well, no :) if someone would ask a question like this, I can give only **guesses**, don't know what the guy in front will figure out about me after this :)

Answer (score 5):

`DateTime` has a precision of 100ns. But on typical implementations, `DateTime.Now` only changes every few milliseconds.

`Datetime.Now != Datetime.Now` can be true, but it's extremely unlikely to happen. This is a typical race conditions of the kind you often see in multi-threaded code. i.e. you should not rely on `DateTime.Now` not changing, but rather store a copy in a local variable.

Comment: is it related to computer frequency clock somehow ?

Comment: It's related to an internal system timer which affects timers, `Thread.Sleep`, `DateTime.Now`, `Environment.TickCount`, thread switching,...

Comment: If i remember correctly `DateTime.Now` is relatively expensive since it  uses IO. Another reason to store a copy. Edit: Here's the link i'm referring to: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10899709/284240

Comment: @TimSchmelter It's expensive because it needs to do time zone conversion. AFAIK the actual time getting part is rather cheap. On my comp `DateTime.UtcNow` costs 9ns, `DateTime.Now` costs 900ns.