# Shorten a DateTime condition check

Tags: c#, conditional-statements

```
if ((DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Friday && DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday) &&
((DateTime.Now.Hour >= 10 && DateTime.Now.Hour < 13) || (DateTime.Now.Hour >= 20 && DateTime.Now.Hour < 23)))
```

I have to shorten this condition, any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you have to?  It's not short, but it's to the point.

Comment: ...but it is not very readable, which is important for understanding the code easier

Comment: @MUG4N - thats what comments are for, if its that bad, spread it over multiple lines, i dont think the logic can be shortened

Comment: You could reduce the `DayOfWeek` check to:  `(Int32)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek < 5`.

Comment: @Sayse I agree with you that you can't shorten the logic but you can improve the readability by choosing sub-methods which self-explaining names. You don't need the comments if you get the method names right.

Comment: @DonBoitnott but then you have the problem of Magic Numbers, i think comparing to enum is "cleaner" (i know this question is about shortening)

Comment: why? just... why? your original method is already plenty readable/maintainable. if you're gonna change it to something absurd, any of these answers will do, might as well go with the ItsPartyTime() option.

Comment: @Master117 I agree totally.  Shorter, not better, is what was requested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could change the hours to use

```
(DateTime.Now.Hour % 12) +1 >= 10 && (DateTime.Now.Hour % 12) +1 < 13
```

Maybe even without the second check.

I don't think you can improve much more than that than looking for other methods like other answers

**Update**
I tested the above and its wrong, but this is more sadistic and works

```
var check = (DateTime.Now.Hours - 10 % 12) % 10;
 var checkV = (DateTime.Now.Hours >= 10 && check < 3);
```

Test Code

```
for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
{
    var check = (i - 10 % 12) % 10;
    bool checkV = (i >= 10 && check < 3);
    Console.WriteLine(i.ToString() + ": " + checkV.ToString());
 }
 Console.ReadKey();
```

**Update 2**
Complete shortened code

```
if(   (int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek < 5 && 
           DateTime.Now.Hours >= 10 && 
         ((DateTime.Now.Hours - 10 % 12) % 10) < 3)
```

Comment: I'm just checking my own logic here. it looks slightly wrong to me lol

Comment: @deltree - I was right, it was wrong, so i became more devilish ;)

Comment: you're right, it's more devilish. I don't understand it anymore.

Comment: @deltree - Make sure hour is >= 10 (Lower bounds check) and then the devilish part: (take the hours subtract 10, get the remainder of that divided by 12, and remained again of result divided by 10, for 10-12 and 20-23, either 0 1 or 2 is returned which is less than 3... Personally i like the original code in OP question

Comment: @Sinros: I didnt know that obfuscation was your objective ;) Btw, this is called codegolf and there's even a stackexchange  site for this kind of puzzles: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @TimSchmelter - I was aiming to answer the "shorten this condition" question... I +1ed your answer way before attempting this :P, I've seen codegolf but the questions always seem to favour shorter handed writing languages

Answer (score 4):

Well, you could build an extension method:

```
public static bool BoundsCheck(this DateTime d, int min, int max, int min2, int max2)
{
    return (d.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Friday &&
        d.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday &&
        d.Hour >= min &&
        d.Hour < max) ||
        (d.Hour >= min2 && d.Hour < max2);
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
if (DateTime.Now.BoundsCheck(10, 13, 20, 23))...
```

Comment: +1 for extension methods, though your parameters could be more clearly named.

Comment: @deltree, thanks! And I'll buy that they could be named better, but I honestly don't even know what to name them because I honestly don't know what the OP is doing here. :D

Comment: perhaps this could be refactored to recieve a list of datetime ranges aka friday 10-13, friday 20-23, etc

Comment: @deltree, I don't think so. The integers are bounds checking the `Hour`

Comment: actually I think you're logic doesn't match the OP here, they check the days against both hour periods as options.

Answer (score 4):

Is this shorter? Maybe, but more important in my opinion it's more readable and maintainable:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var notAllowedDays = new[] { DayOfWeek.Friday, DayOfWeek.Saturday };
var allowedHours = Enumerable.Range(10, 3).Concat(Enumerable.Range(20, 3));
if(!notAllowedDays.Contains(now.DayOfWeek) && allowedHours.Contains(now.Hour))
{

}
```

Comment: I'm afraid the readable part dies when you're not a Linq guru :)

Comment: This is a reasonable solution but I'd personally prefer the original conditional.

Comment: I prefer using the "now" variable because nano-seconds pass between each check, so this is more accurate.

Comment: @deltree: Yes, `Now` is also a relatively expensive "property". It even needs to use `IO` acces: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10900267/284240

Comment: IMHO it's even more readable and understandable if both days and hours are either allowed or notAllowed. Less thinking involved :) But that's just nitpicking.

Comment: @BorisB.: Agreed! However, i've tried to keep as close as possible to OP's logic.... and i was too lazy to type all days apart from `DayOfWeek.Friday, DayOfWeek.Saturday` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
if (!this.ItsPartyDay() && (this.ItsLunchTime() || this.ItsDinnerTime()))
{
    ...
}

private bool ItsPartyDay()
{
    return (Int32)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek >= 5;
}

private bool ItsLunchTime()
{
    return (DateTime.Now.Hour >= 10 && DateTime.Now.Hour < 13);
}

private bool ItsDinnerTime()
{
    return (DateTime.Now.Hour >= 20 && DateTime.Now.Hour < 23);
}
```

Comment: this is how refactoring is fun.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any reasonable solution but here a couple that come to mind. Use aliases for `DateTime` and `DayOfWeek`. One other option would be to assign all of those values to variables before the conditional.

So you could do things like;

```
 string fri = DayOfWeek.Friday;
 string sat = DayOfWeek.Saturday;
```

then use those in the conditional. Or;

```
 using dt = DateTime;
```

Then you could do `dt.Now.DayOfWeek`

I personally would not recommend doing either of these things. You're not actually shortening the conditional, you're just refactoring. If you have a lot of these in one class it might be worth the trade off, otherwise it's probably not.

EDIT: The extension method suggestion by Michael Perrenoud is a reasonable solution that actually works really well.