# Performance of datetime.datetime.now in multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

In writing some parallel code using python multiprocessing, I noticed strange performance behavior differences between running the code on my Mac laptop and a windows server machine. The Mac laptop is about twice as fast as the windows machine when I run the code serially, but was twice as slow when running with 2 cores, and it's performance plateaued with more cores (still under the total core count), while the windows machine showed decent scaling.

Poking around with cProfile, I realized that using multiple cores, the Mac was spending almost all of its time calling `datetime.datetime.now`, which is used to do some internal timing, using the following context manager:

```
class timer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.timer = datetime.datetime.now

    def __enter__(self):
        self.start = self.timer()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *arg):
        self.end = self.timer()
        self.elapsed = (self.end - self.start)
```

which is used something like:

```
with timer() as t:
    <run some code>
total_time += t.elapsed
```

When I modify the code to not call `datetime.datetime.now` and set `self.elapsed = datetime.timedelta(0)`, I recover the proper parallel scaling.

I don't see this behavior under Windows, so I'm wondering why OSX would take a performance hit calling `now()` from multiple processes. Calling two serial instances of the program does not result in one process effecting the other's performance vs a single serial run.

Does anyone have an explanation for this behavior? I'm using Python 2.7.10 on both machines.

Comment: It sounds as though OS X is taking some kind of system-wide lock when you check the time.  I don't see why that should be necessary, though.  Perhaps it needs to atomically copy the system time or something?

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899709/datetime-now-causes-io-blocking) might give an explanation.

My guess is that MAC OS does not allow concurrent read access to the real time clock. Therefore, only one process at the time can read that value considerably dropping the performance.

To validate the answer given in the above link, you might check if the processes are actually suspended for IO wait when they read the time. Just spawn a multitude of processes only reading the time and check if they get suspended in IO Wait.